# CakePHP 2.1 --> CustomAuthorization class not working properly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I used the cookbook to create my own custom Authentication using the following code:

```
// Controller/Auth/CustomAuthenticate.php



App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class CustomAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {

    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        return false;
    }
} 

// Controller/UserController.php


class UserController extends AppController {
   var $components = array('Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Custom')));

   public function login() {
      // some code that includes:
      $this->Auth->login($this->request->data);
   }
}
```

Somehow with correct credentials, the login seems to work, although the authenticate method in my CustomAuthentication class returns false.

I'm using CakePHP 2.1

Comment: Probably because that is all your `authenticate()` method does...is return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot expect this to work propery because you are not supposed to pass `$this->request->data` on login forms.

it is just

```
$this->Auth->login();
```

otherwise you are skipping authenticate and the passed data will ALWAYS log this user in. regardless if it is garbige or the correct credentials. never ever do that with login forms.

Comment: That's not true... http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in, besides that, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: you do have 2.x, dont you? the very same link you just pointed out states that you stand corrected: "In 2.0 $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in with whatever data is posted" => thats just what i said. And it is also the answer why your code behaves this way. you are skipping your authenticate() method with your forced login. you might confuse authenticate with authorize, though.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! This is a major change since 1.3 and gave me a big headache. Thx!